# Integers from strings

Tags: java

Hey guys am hoping you could help me with this.
Am trying to get all the integers from this code, just leaving the letters behind and am seriously lost here

```
public class Tie {

    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        String fr = "4544FF";
        int yu = fr.length();
        System.out.print(yu);

    }

}
```

Comment: That... doesn't look like much of an effort at all. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How does getting the length and printing it out remotely accomplish what you try to do?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean the input is "4544FF" and the output should be "FF"? Or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @VivinPaliath could just get the length and change to uppercase or lowercase that's all

Comment: @JeroenVannevel just to show you that that's what I could do with the string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Tie {

    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        Tie tie = new Tie();
        String fr = "4544FF";
        char[] strings = fr.toCharArray();
        List<Integer>integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
            if(tie.validationNumber(strings[i]+"")){
                integers.add(Integer.parseInt(strings[i]+""));
            }
        }
        for(Integer i:integers){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public boolean validationNumber(String s){

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only seek to remove the numeric digits from the string, use regex and replace, with regex 'd' you can filter on all digits.

```
String fr = "4544FF";
fr = fr.replaceAll("\\d","");
//result should be that fr now is contains only "FF", because the digits have bee replaced with nothing.
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work, if my little experience with regex serves me right.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use this method substring(int start, int final).

```
public static void main(String agrs[]){
    String fr = "4544FF";

    String numbers= fr.substring(0, 4);
    String letters= fr.substring(4);

    System.out.println("It will shows 4544" + numbers);

    System.out.println("It will shows FF" + letters);

    int convertNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbers); //Convert to int

    System.out.println("" +convertNumber);

}
```

It will show you only the numbers 4544.

I hope that solve your problem.